# How to clear a text file that is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, string, process, filestream

A certain textfile is continuously occupied by another process to update its contents and I need my application to clear its contents once in a while. I'm thinking FileStream's fileshare.ReadWrite property might be of use but I'm not 100% certain.

How can I clear a textfile that is owned by another process?

Comment: This will depend on what flag the other process used when it opened the file. If it locked it exclusively you can simply forget about modifying this file from your process without killing the owning process to release the handle. Another possibility is of course to modify the other process so that it doesn't lock the file exclusively when opening the handle.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov probably won't work anyway.  Assuming the other process has allocated file size N and is writing to the end of the file, he can't truncate it, right?

Comment: @ChrisShain, as I said, this will depend on what flag the other process used when opening the handle to this file.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov That being the case, how do I verify the flag?

Comment: If you have the source code of the other process you simple take a look at it or you could use a tool such as [SysInternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and then look for a call to the CreateFile or CreateFileEx Win32 API on the process. It will then give you the parameters that were passed to this function and the different flags that were used.

Comment: You _may_ be able to get around this by virtualising the location the other process is writing to (add an abstraction layer between the logical directory and logical disk). This would be a sledgehammer to crack a nut though and you might cause the other process to die in interesting and unusual ways if it's not well written. If you really want to do this, [see this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21329/QVFS-A-FAT32-Based-Virtual-File-System-Powered-by) for a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Why not just overwrite the txt file with an empty string?

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("filepath to the txt doc", emptystring make sure to initialize);
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the OP can't get Write access to the file so can't delete or overwrite